# Hive split string to get all the items except last one

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

why below solution doesn't work when the string is split by period sign (.) .

```
select regexp_extract('test,data,fd,dfd','^(.*?)(?:,)(.*)$', 2) from tablename;

input :     193.54.23.456
out put :   193.54.23
```

Comment: the solution works for , separated strings but not working for . separated items.

Comment: Your current transformation also does not work as you described. group 2 which you are extracting should be data,fd,dfd. Group 1 = test.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract all elements of comma or dot separated string, use this `'^(.*?)(?:[.,])([^,.]*)$'` regex and extract group number 1.

Regex meaning:

`^` - beginning of the string anchor

`(.*?)` - group number 1, any character any times not greedy, this group will capture what you need to extract

`(?:[.,])` - dot or comma, this group is not indexed for extract because it is not capturing group (?: means not capturing)

`([^,.]*?)` --capturing group number 2 - any character except dot and comma any times. This group has index 2 and will capture last element and can be extracted if necessary using index 2.

Demo:

```
--separated by dot
regexp_extract('test.data.fd.dfd','^(.*?)(?:[.,])([^,.]*)$', 1) --returns test.data.fd
regexp_extract('test.data.fd.dfd','^(.*?)(?:[.,])([^,.]*)$', 2) --returns dfd

--the same regex with comma separated
regexp_extract('test,data,fd,dfd','^(.*?)(?:[.,])([^,.]*)$', 1) --returns test.data.fd
regexp_extract('test,data,fd,dfd','^(.*?)(?:[.,])([^,.]*)$', 2) --returns dfd
```

Inside character class [] you do not need to escape dot.